# What does the '+' symbol mean when opening a buffer?

Tags: buffers, neovim

I want to open a terminal buffer in a vertical split.

If i try `:vertical split terminal` I get a buffer named 'terminal', not a terminal buffer.

I recently learned I could do `:vertical split +terminal` to open a terminal buffer, but I have not been able to find the help docs explaining what the + is doing.

What does the '+' mean, is it specific to terminal buffers or is it a more generic thing?

P.S.

I also just realized I can do `:vertical split | terminal` to get the same behavior (at least I think its the same).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Should have looked a bit harder before asking, I found my answer:

`:help +cmd`

```
                            *+cmd* *[+cmd]*
The [+cmd] argument can be used to position the cursor in the newly opened
file, or execute any other command:
    +       Start at the last line.
    +{num}      Start at line {num}.
    +/{pat}     Start at first line containing {pat}.
    +{command}  Execute {command} after opening the new file.
                {command} is any Ex command.
```

Comment: These also work in the command line, e.g. type `vim system.log +` to open `system.log` and jump to the end of the file.